# How to call unregisterReceiver on a BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a couple of activities that extends from a custom class I wrote which in turn extends from `Activity`. I've named this class `LoginFinisherActivity` and on overriden its `onCreate` function like this

```
private BroadcastReceiver finishReceiver = null;
public static final String ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN = "ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("LoginFinisherActivity", "onCreate() called.");
    finishReceiver = new FinishReceiver();
    registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN));
}
```

Now the activities that extended `LoginFinisherActivity` are the ones that need to retain their states whenever I click the system's back button. i.e. I'm at a welcome activity and I want to go to and forth to a sign up/sign in activities. But when I either sign in or sign up, I land on `NavigationActivity` which extends `Activity`, i.e. it needs to be closed down not gone back to whichever activity it came from. 
I was able to do that if I removed the `onPause` and `onResume` functions from the `LoginFinisherActivity`. 
My `FinishReceiver`'s code is as follows:

```
private final class FinishReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

**Edit:** following are the overriden `onPause` and `onResume` functions in the `LoginFinisherActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("LoginFinisherActivity", "onPaused() called.");
    super.onPause();
    if(finishReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(finishReceiver);
        finishReceiver = null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("LoginFinisherActivity", "onResume() called.");
    super.onResume();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN)) {
        finish();
    }
    else {
        if(finishReceiver == null)
            registerReceiver(finishReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_FINISH_LOGIN));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue, after all?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The NavigationClass extends the behavior of `LoginFinisherClass` i.e. does not close the application rather loads the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to finish your activities on successful login/register, I think the best approach would be using startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int REQUEST_CODE) instead of handling more intents that make the flow more complex.

You can also make use of android.support.v4.content.IntentCompatIntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(...) if you want to terminate the previous stack of activities.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I want to finish WelcomeActivity and Login/Register (either one of the activities which user came from) upon successful login or registration. These activities shall also be removed from the heap and their drawables items cleared. 
Could you elaborate more on startActivityForResult? I'm sorry, kind of new in the Android arena.

Comment: Where do I use this code exactly? In my current setting (after removing onPause and onResume functions)?

Comment: When you do a successful login/register you start another activity, right? In that point instead of using **startActivity** try using **IntentCompatIntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask**. I think that will fix your issue.

Comment: Would that also remove all the resources (drawables, class references, etc) hold by the previous activities?

Comment: That will restart the task, so yes. You can check the docs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html If you wanna be sure all resources are freed, you can run a memory allocation test (but this is a little more advance topic you can catch up later).

Comment: Sure! Let me try and familiarize myself with the function and use it in my code.